# How to move a diagram between projects?

Tags: uml, diagram, enterprise-architect

I'm a very basic user of EA. I never had the time to learn its terminology or features and therefore i only use it to create pretty basic (yet rather big) diagrams.

Unfortunately my EA project file was updated by another person and now i need to move a diagram from the old version to the new one.
I thought this could be a simple copy-paste action but it doesn't seem to be possible.

Any idea how to move the diagram to the new project file?
(keep in mind i don't really care about keeping elements or whatever)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is likely the following (assuming that all elements are still present and only the diagram has been changed and the *other* project is something like a previous backup version):

1. Enter the old project
2. Create a dummy package
3. Move the diagram in question into that package
4. Export the package as XMI
5. Enter the recent repository
6. Import the package from the XMI
7. Voila, there is your diagram. You can replace the old one or keep both as you wish
8. Remove the dummy package as you will no longer need it

Answer (score 2):

In the more recent version (v10 IIRC) you can copy/paste packages from one model to another using

**Right click | Copy / Paste | Copy Package to Clipboard**

Then go to the other project and choose

**Right click | Copy / Paste | Paste Package from Clipboard**

Which is a bit easier then xmi import/export

Comment: That seems to work indeed. Once you got used to some methods it's hard to adopt a new one. Even if it's easier to use.

Comment: Would be awesome but unfortunately i'm using v9. Thanks anyways!